# Is the value function convex wrt a parameter if linear in that parameter and not in constraint?

Tags: convex-optimization

For a convex optimization problem with equality constraints:

Max $f(\boldsymbol{x},a)$  subject to $g(\boldsymbol{x})=0$.

$a$ is a parameter and the function $f(\boldsymbol{x},a)$ is convex in $x_i$.
Note the parameter $a$ is not in the constraint.

Question is: if $f(\boldsymbol{x},a)$ is linear in $a$ is the value function convex?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correct, then:

1. $f(\mathbf{x}, a)=af_1(\mathbf{x})$
2. $f_1(t\mathbf{x_1} + (1-t)\mathbf{x_2}) \leq tf_1(\mathbf{x_1}) + (1-t)f_1(\mathbf{x_2})$ since $f(\mathbf{x}, a)$ is convex in $x_i$

We then have, for $a\geq 0$:

$f(t\mathbf{x_1} + (1-t)\mathbf{x_2}, a) = af_1(t\mathbf{x_1} + (1-t)\mathbf{x_2}) \leq taf_1(\mathbf{x_1}) + (1-t)af_1(\mathbf{x_2}) = tf(\mathbf{x_1}, a) + (1-t)f(\mathbf{x_2},a)$

which imply that $f(\mathbf{x},a)$ is convex for $a\geq 0$. If $a<0$ then $f(\mathbf{x}, a)$ would be concave.

Comment: I think this is only true when $a \geq 0$.

Comment: True. If a<0 then it would be concave.